# Paypal payKey brings me to incorrect payment

Tags: c#, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments, paypal

I'm trying to create an API call to create a split payment. Upon creating the `AdaptivePaymentService` and calling the `Pay` method, it returns a `PayResponse` that shows `SUCCESS`. However, when I get the `payKey` and open the page at https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_ap-payment&paykey=, it brings me to some random page that usually says some error along the lines of "This transaction has already been approved. Please visit your PayPal Account Overview to see the details.", and in the top right, it'll show "Fiverr.com" or some other random webpage. I've verified that the `payKey` I am receiving is sent along with a`SUCCESS` message, so I don't understand why this is invalid. The following code is what I am using.

```
        ReceiverList receiverList = new ReceiverList();
        receiverList.receiver = new List<Receiver>();
        RequestEnvelope requestEnvelope = new RequestEnvelope("en_US");

        Dictionary<string, string> configurationMap = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        configurationMap.Add("account1.apiUsername", "----");
        configurationMap.Add("account1.apiPassword", "----");
        configurationMap.Add("account1.apiSignature", "----");
        configurationMap.Add("account1.applicationId", "APP-80W284485P519543T");

        configurationMap.Add("mode", "sandbox");

        Receiver receiver1 = new Receiver();
        receiver1.amount = ((decimal?)9.00);
        receiver1.email = "rbxtrade-seller@gmail.com";

        receiverList.receiver.Add(receiver1);

        Receiver receiver2 = new Receiver();
        receiver2.amount = ((decimal?)2.00);
        receiver2.email = "rbxtrade-buyer@gmail.com";

        receiverList.receiver.Add(receiver2);

        PayRequest request = new PayRequest(requestEnvelope, "PAY", "https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/ap_parallel_payment/dotnet?cancel=true", "USD", receiverList, "https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/ap_parallel_payment/dotnet?success=true");

        AdaptivePaymentsService service = new AdaptivePaymentsService(configurationMap);
        PayResponse response = service.Pay(request);

        if (!response.responseEnvelope.ack.ToString().Trim().ToUpper().Equals(AckCode.FAILURE.ToString()) && !response.responseEnvelope.ack.ToString().Trim().ToUpper().Equals(AckCode.FAILUREWITHWARNING.ToString()))
        {
            Process.Start("https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_ap-payment&paykey=" + response.payKey); //opens the webpage
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("E:" + String.Join("\n", response.error.Select((x) => x.message)));
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am currently facing this problem in java.

Try returning to this: "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_ap-payment&paykey=" + paykey. It is supposed to work with this.

It's all I found, but it DIDN'T work for me.

Comment: Nevermind! That actually fixed it! I have NO idea what weird URL I was using, this got it to work! A million thanks!

Comment: Hmm, it seems the error happened again, but installing a Cookie editor and clearing all .paypal cookies seems to fix the issue. Strange, because I had the same problem on multiple machines. Huh.

Comment: So what should i do to get it working ? I am using this URL but it doesn't work. You're saying that i should clear cookies?

Comment: Try clearing all cookies in your browser and then use the link provided.

Comment: It worked with another browser. The cookies were indeed the problem. Thanks